# JUCE assertion failure - IIRFilter on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, audio, juce

I’m having trouble with IIRFilter in an iOS Audio Application.

I used the setCoefficients method on a slider change, but when I move the slider, I get crackling and then the app freezes and I get a Juce Assertion Failure.

[IIRFilter Assertion Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4oER.png)

Here is where I change the coefficients to correspond to the frequency slider:

[Changing filter coefficient on sliderValueChanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwD0t.png)

But I don’t see how it’s failing. I’ve set the range for the lpfSlider to be from 20 to 20k in the MainContentComponenet constructor here:

[Setting range for Frequency slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHDnR.png)

and from my understanding, iOS audio data from the microphone is sampled at 44.1 kHz.

Here is where I define the global sample rate, fs, in prepareToPlay():

[Setting global sample rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPj2D.png)

So why is this assertion failing?

Anyone know what’s going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I googled the assertion in your screen shot, found the cpp file and the assertion.

```
jassert (frequency > 0.0 && frequency <= sampleRate * 0.5);
```

Either your assumption about the sample rate is wrong or your slider is allowing the frequency to extend beyond Nyquist or below 0.

The crackling is a natural side-effect of abruptly changing filter coefficients.

Comment: Hey Jaket, thanks for taking time on this for me. I had already checked the assertion, myself. The Nyquist is definitely 44.1k/2 (I had the sample rate from preparetoplay printed to the screen) and my slider's range is definitely 20 to 20k. So something else is going on here.

Comment: You are ignoring the obvious.  You call `makeLowPassFilter(frequency, sampleRate)`.  `makeLowPassFilter` fails the assert.  Despite what you say, your frequency and/or sample rate are not what you think they are. I would start by putting two separate asserts, one on the frequency and one on the sample rate, immediately before the call to `makeLowPassFilter`.

Comment: You were right. Sample rate was 22050. I'm just confused as to why it changed..?? I set the max range of the slider to be dependent on the sample rate. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewDoss. Glad you got it worked out. Please accept this answer if it worked for you. Thanks!